# In Django, can you automatically map URLs to view methods?

Tags: django, django-urls

Given a view like this:

```
# my_app/views.py
def index(request):
    ...
def list(request):
    ...
def about(request):
    ...
```

Instead of explicitly declaring the urls in `urls.py` for each method in the view:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^index$', 'my_app.views.index'),
url(r'^list$', 'my_app.views.list'),
url(r'^about$', 'my_app.views.about'),
...
```

Is it possible to just give the URL dispatcher the view (`my_apps.views`) and have it handle all the view's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can have one view that captures a url regexp,

`r'^(?P<viewtype>index|list|about)/$', 'myview'`

with a view that handles the captured parameter.

```
def myview(request, viewtype):
    if viewtype == 'index':
          return http.HttpResponse("I'm the index view")
    elif viewtype == 'list':
          return http.HttpResponse("I'm the list view')
```

But I'd really recommend keeping your view logic separated for clarity.  It's much easier to follow 3 different views with their specific functions than 3 if / then statements.

Comment: Yeah, I stuck with the explicit declarations per view method.  I didn't have too many to make it necessary to clean up my `urls.py`. Thanks!

Comment: I think that's the right call :) For me, if I needed to clean up urls.py, I'd use `include(new_urls)` and keep a new urls in the same app as the view.

Comment: the advantage is that it is really useful in development as you keep adding / removing view methods to not have to think about syncing up the urls.py with the methods in the view. PlayFramework for example accomplishes this by allowing you to parse url fragments as controller / method names